# Spot The Difference

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, random

## Challenge

Generate two \$16 \times 16\$ grids, each initially filled with "@" symbols and spaces. Each cell in the grids should be independently filled with an "@" or a space, with each character having an equal probability (\$50\%\$) of being chosen for each cell. This ensures that both grids start off identically, with all possible configurations of each grid having the same probability of occurrence, corresponding to a uniform distribution across all possible grid states.

After generating these identical grids, modify a single, randomly selected cell in the second grid by either adding or removing an "@" symbol. This modification guarantees that the second grid differs from the first grid in exactly one position. The selection of this cell must be uniformly random from among the \$256\$ cells, ensuring that each cell has an equal chance (\$\frac{1}{256}\$) of being chosen for modification.

**Input**

None

**Output**

Both grids side by side, separated by a vertical bar "|", to visually compare them and spot the single difference. e.g. row \$3\$, col \$10\$.

```
@ @ @ @   @ @ @@|@ @ @ @   @ @ @@
 @@@ @@   @    @| @@@ @@   @    @
 @ @@@@@@ @   @ | @ @@@@@@@@   @ 
  @  @  @@ @@ @ |  @  @  @@ @@ @ 
@@@  @@ @@  @  @|@@@  @@ @@  @  @
  @ @   @ @@  @@|  @ @   @ @@  @@
@ @ @@ @  @@ @@@|@ @ @@ @  @@ @@@
@ @       @@    |@ @       @@    
    @ @@   @@@ @|    @ @@   @@@ @
 @@ @    @@ @@  | @@ @    @@ @@  
@    @@@@   @ @@|@    @@@@   @ @@
@@ @@ @@  @@@ @@|@@ @@ @@  @@@ @@
 @@@ @ @@    @ @| @@@ @ @@    @ @
   @ @  @  @ @  |   @ @  @  @ @  
@@@@ @@@@@ @  @@|@@@@ @@@@@ @  @@
 @  @@@ @@@@ @@@| @  @@@ @@@@ @@@
```

Comment: Do the characters have to be `@`, `|`, and space? Also just to make sure, we don't have to output the position of the difference right?

Comment: This task seems so random. Is there some purpose to it?

Comment: Just a random idea to create a simple [Spot The Difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spot_the_difference) puzzle.

Comment: Are the grids random? Is this challenge missing [random] tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>25</s>  22 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
⁹ḶẊ⁾ @Ẋḷ\⁹¡¥Ɱs⁴Z€j€”|Y
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R486HO7Y93NX1qHGfggOQfrhjewxQ8NDCQ0sfbVxX/KhxS9SjpjVZQPyoYW5N5P//AA)**

#### How?

```
⁹ḶẊ⁾ @Ẋḷ\⁹¡¥Ɱs⁴Z€j€”|Y - Link: no arguments
⁹                      - 256
 Ḷ                     - lowered range {256} -> [0..255]
  Ẋ                    - shuffle -> IsEqualIndicators
   ⁾ @                 - list of characters -> " @"
            Ɱ          - map across {i in IsEqualIndicators} with:
           ¥           -   last two links as a dyad - f(" @", i):
      Ẋ                -     shuffle {" @"} -> " @" or "@ "
         ⁹¡            -   repeat {i} times: (i.e. a no-op when i=0)
        \              -     cumulative reduce {ShuffledCharacters} by:
       ḷ               -       left argument
                            (first takes " @" to "  ", or "@ " to "@@"
                             then further applications have no more effect)
             s⁴        - split into chunks of 16
               Z€      - transpose each
                 j€”|  - join each with '|'
                     Y - join with newlines
```

---

[Here](https://tio.run/##XZExDsIwDEV3n@LvIHECJF@DjYWl6gWQPAArZ2BiZWRBlRi4SXuRkMR22rpDk7x@@/@43anvzymNw3v8PKfba7o8ZL/Lm3G4T9cvNttjPnT25fAbUkoMZgaQ1/JmiYDKyjOFRECA67k8WREAQStQS/JeIiDr5QASAbmctXFRrAG5n4arijWgORZa0hUgbqHVWSKwHuxXZIlAe2hVbSwRkKvdWmwMDZDlgVXYf1kAn2mzlghIY9l06m0DIF76VpcA/g) is a difference spotter which accepts an output and replaces any space on one of the two sides where there is an `@` on the other with a `+`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>147</s> <s>141</s> <s>139</s> <s>138</s> 124 bytes

*-8 bytes thanks to [Mukundan314](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/91267). -14 bytes thanks to [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748).*

```python
from random import*
g=getrandbits
n=g(4)
r=16
while r:r-=1;s=g(16);print(f'{s:16b}|{s^(r==n)<<g(4):16b}'.translate('@ '*25))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxbCsMgFAX/XYV/aqAF@5CS5EJXUkioMUKicr1QStq129ivgRnOSW@aYzjfEpYyYVw5DuG5w68pIjXMgbNU3egpswBOXhRD0Ia9Zr9Yji0eQHd5D9qoLqEPJCex5Vab8fvZ8kMiQFB9X5d/KY71MC8DWSnuXDSnq1Kl/AA)

### Explanation (outdated)

That's a lot of use out of Python's [`random` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html). First, it iterates over \$[0, 16)\$ shuffled with `for r in sample(a:=range(16),16)`. The random ordering means that `r` will only be zero once, but it can be on any of the 16 iterations. When this is the case, the row that it outputs in that iteration will contain the difference.

It represents cells as bits and therefore, rows as 16-bit integers. Luckily, `getrandbits(16)` can generate a random 16-bit integer like `16846` or `01000001110011102`. (Though `randrange(65536)` or `randint(0,65535)` would've worked just as well.)

Now, for the interesting bit manipulation. To toggle a random cell, it takes the bitwise XOR of the row with a 16-bit integer that has only one randomly chosen bit turned on like `00010000000000002`. This integer can be made by left shifting 1 bitwise by a random integer in \$[0, 16)\$. When `r` is zero, `r<1` is `True`, which can be used as if it were `1` in numerical operations. `choice(a)` returns a random choice from \$[0, 16)\$. Therefore, `s^(r<1)<<choice(a)` computes something like:

```
   00000000000000012
<<               12
-------------------- 
   00010000000000002
 ^ 01000001110011102
-------------------- 
   01010001110011102
```

However, when `r` is not zero, left shifting `False` or `0` bitwise or  taking the bitwise XOR of it with something does nothing.

Finally, in order to represent it as a string and turn the bits into `@`s and spaces, it first uses a format string `{s:16b}`. This converts the integer into binary and pads it with enough spaces to increase its length to 16, turning `16846` into `' 100000111001110'`. It then uses `.translate({49:64,48:32})` (a table of the characters' respective ASCII ordinal numbers) to turn it into `' @     @@@  @@@ '`.

Comment: Save seven bytes by only using `getrandbits` for all your random needs - [TIO](https://tio.run/##HYzdCsIgGIbPvQrPphHBmsiyeSvBRmpC@5RPT8J27aYdPfC8P/GTXwGmOWKtFsNOcYVng99jwHwiTjuTu9t8TgS0Y4ITG5Ai9dDLzrBRcpVa0niP6CEzO5SkRrkd35IeDLUGvix9@pfDpT@m95oNK@KmpDiLWU3Xg/Nafw)

Comment: Make that eight switching to a while loop [TIO](https://tio.run/##HYzRCoMgGEbvfYru0rENXCJl@SqDYmZCqfz@MEbr2V3u6sA5fF/84BJ800bIeYawVTD61wm3xQB4IVZbg8VNDhPx2lLBCGguyXtxq6lAwU3zPp2BS9ZHcB7pXO9JcTkd3z09KWjt2TCU5V/W93KY1hEN3UWnpLiKVjWPg7Gcfw)

Comment: ...make that fourteen by using a string, `'@ '*25`, rather than an ordinal map in your translation - [TIO](https://tio.run/##HYxbCsMgFAX/XYV/aqAF@5CS5EJXUkioMUKicr1QStq129ivgRnOSW@aYzjfEpYyYVw5DuG5w68pIjXMgbNU3egpswBOXhRD0Ia9Zr9Yji0eQHd5D9qoLqEPJCex5Vab8fvZ8kMiQFB9X5d/KY71MC8DWSnuXDSnq1Kl/AA)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Thanks, thanks, and... wait, `str.translate` can do that? That function's always been in my blind spot... Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## Google Sheets, <del>170</del> 161 bytes

Formula in \$A1\$

```cpp
=INDEX(LET(g,MAP(A25:P40,LAMBDA(_,IF(COINFLIP(),"@"," "))),r,ROW(1:16),{g,IF(r,"|"),IF((r=RANDBETWEEN(1,16))*(TOROW(r)=RANDBETWEEN(1,16)),IF(g="@"," ","@"),g)}))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! Save 6 bytes with `map(A25:P40,lambda(_` instead of `makearray()` and another 3 bytes with `if(g="@"," ","@")` instead of `ifs()`.

Comment: @doubleunary, thanks! I initally had `IFS(g="@"," ",g=" ","@")` and changed it to `IFS(g="@"," ",1,"@")` I didn't think of using `IF`. (:

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>41 38</s> 37 bytes

```
' @|'{~(?@$&2([,.2,.~:)?|.{.&1)@16 16
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/pvqWhlGGumaGWprs6lpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/1RUcatSr6zTsHVTUjDSidfSMdPTqrDTta/Sq9dQMNR0MzRQMzf5rcqUmZ@QrpKmr/wcA)

*-1 thanks to Mukundan314*

- `?|.{.&1` Create a 16x16 grid of zeros with a 1 in the upper left, and randomly rotate it to one of the 256 possible positions
- `?@$&2` Create a 16x16 grid of random 0-1s
- `[,.2` Zip that grid with 2, to make the dividing wall
- `,.~:` Then zip *that* with "where is the random grid not equal to the random-single-1 grid"
- `' @|'{~` Translate all that to the appropriate ascii chars

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 107 bytes

A full program.

```javascript
for(R=Math.random,v=R(n=16)*512|0;n--;print(s))for(k=33,m=R(s="")*2**k;k--;)s+=" @|"[k-16?m>>k%17&1^!v--:2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcrRCsIgFADQXymhUNuNdLQiuasf6GWvUSBFtC66oeLT/t3WeT5fm218hn5MkI@lvIfAO7za9NkG61@DqzJ23KNqhNwrPe2MBzBj6H3iUYh/J6zrys0rImNCainJ0JxE3CBbXCZ2I1DN2bUtrdRhrR7LDHDS91J@)

---

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 106 bytes

```c
f(v,n,m,k){for(v=rand(n=16)&511;n--;)for(m=rand(k=33);~k--;)putchar(~k?k-16?32<<(m>>k%17&1^!v--):124:10);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYzdCoIwGEDve4p1kXwfOPDTMnD@vEkwVjOZW6FmF6KP3tK6OnAOHMVrpbzXMIYutKHBST86GItOuiu4glIMTkTCcS5wK/ZfTJEkKBaz6edrUHfZwWIqwymtkjjPwZalOdA5oMt@5Bwzio8ZRShm37iBWdk4QDbtGOt/v6GxN4gQxWo0rJj9R@lW1r3n7y8)

Answer (score 3):

## APL+WIN, <s>54</s> 46 bytes

Index origin = 0

```
'@ |'[(2|z+m⍴(?i)⌽i↑1),2,z←(m←2⍴16)⍴2|i?i←256]
```

[Try it online!Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlwPWooz3tv7qDQo16tIZRTZV27qPeLRr2mZqPevZmPmqbaKipY6RTBVSpkQskjICShmaaQNKoJtM@EyRiahb7H2gG1/80Li4A)

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>112</s> 111 bytes

```r
s=sample
A=B=s(2,256,T)
B[i]=3-B[i<-s(256,1)]
`?`=\(v)matrix(c("@"," ")[v],16)
cat(rbind(?A,"|",?B,"
"),sep="")
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMFa5eLUEr3i1NQUDRMjzaWlJWm6Fjfzi22LE3MLclK5HG2dbIs1jHSMTM10QjS5nKIzY22NdYGUjS5QGChoqBnLlWCfYBujUaaZm1hSlFmhkayh5KCko6SgpBldFqtjaKbJlZxYolGUlJmXomHvqKNUo6Rj76SjxKWkqVOcWmCrpAS1dgGUgtIA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) <sup>[SBCS](https://tinyurl.com/Uiua-SBCS-Jan-14)</sup>, <s>36</s> <s>35</s> 34 bytes

```
⊏⍉⊂⊂:↥2⊢.⍜⊡¬⌊×16⊟⚂⚂.⁅⊞⋅⋅⚂.⊚16"@ |"
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_9_0__ZiDihpAg4oqP4o2J4oqC4oqCOisy4oqaMTbijZziiqHCrOKMisOXMTbiip_imoLimoIu4oGF4oqe4ouF4ouF4pqCLuKKmjE2IkAgfCIKCuKJoSZwIGYK)

```
⊏⍉⊂⊂:↥2⊢.⍜⊡¬⌊×16⊟⚂⚂.⁅⊞⋅⋅⚂.⊚16"@ |"
                             "@ |"  # push string
                    ⁅⊞⋅⋅⚂.⊚16       # 16x16 binary random matrix
                   .                # duplicate
         ⍜⊡¬⌊×16⊟⚂⚂                 # invert a random cell
   ⊂:↥2⊢.                           # append row of 2s
  ⊂                                 # prepend original matrix
 ⍉                                  # transpose
⊏                                   # convert to proper ascii symbols
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 92 bytes

```perl
@s=map{(@z=map{('@',$")[rand 2]}0..15),'|',@z,$/}0..15;$s[34*(0|rand 16)+rand 16]^='`';say@s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/9@h2DY3saBaw6EKQqs7qOuoKGlGFyXmpSgYxdYa6OkZmmrqqNeo6zhU6ajoQwSsVYqjjU20NAxqwOoMzTS1oYzYOFv1BHXr4sRKh@L////lF5Rk5ucV/9f1NdUzMDQAAA)

Answer (score 2):

## Google Sheets, 178 bytes

```
=index(let(y,row(1:16),x,torow(y),t,(x=randbetween(1,16))*(y=randbetween(1,16)),g,map(t,lambda(_,if(coinflip()," ","@"))),{g,if(y,"|"),if(t,if(""=tocol(if(t,g,),1),"@"," "),g)}))
```

Put the formula in cell `A1`.

[image: spotdiff.png]

Ungolfed:

```
=arrayformula(let( 
  y, sequence(16), 
  x, transpose(y),
  truthyTable, (x = randbetween(1, 16)) * (y = randbetween(1, 16)), 
  firstGrid, map(truthyTable, lambda(_, if(coinflip(), "@", " "))), 
  currentChar, tocol(if(truthyTable, firstGrid, iferror(ø)), 1), 
  flipChar, if(" " = currentChar, "@", " "), 
  secondGrid, if(truthyTable, flipChar, firstGrid), 
  hstack(firstGrid, if(y, "|"), secondGrid) 
))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>49</s> 48 bytes

```
16*$(16*$( @)¶
(.){2}
$?1
.+
$&|$&
@T` @`@ ` |@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/n8vQTEtFA0woOGge2saloadZbVTLpWJvyKWnzaWiVqOixuUQkqDgkOCgkKBQ4/D/PwA) Edit: Saved 1 byte thanks to @Leo. Explanation:

```
16*$(16*$( @)¶
```

Insert a 16×16 grid of pairs of spaces and `@`s.

```
(.){2}
$?1
```

Pick a random character from each pair.

```
.+
$&|$&
```

Duplicate each row joined with `|`.

```
@T` @`@ ` |@
```

Flip a random space or `@`.

16-byte difference spotter written in [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d):

```
+`@(.{16})@
 $1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZExDsIwDEX3fwoPHUBIlbow@ygwMHTpgNgwZw9JbKftl9pYfUqe/dP367Nuz1JuD73M3@X@uypkWqQUUdX6ivgjxgCtOmtU1BhAxpefSceQIIxhrjsYwKsbGjUGSHs2MwbIqSSsxgASB9xcHQy6w6fKtAT6pHE3noUB@prhtKc9A@zC0eUMEK4U1y4EcPgDsjsOwG8s8rdqDDCiRXdj8Ac) Removes all of the paired `@`s.

Comment: Wow, I have tried to solve this in Retina and ended up with almost exactly the same solution: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/n8vQTEtFA0woOGge2qbJpaGnCURcKvZqXHraXCoGNSoGXCEOCQ4KCQoOCQo1Dv//AwA "Retina – Try It Online")
I didn't realise you could omit the closing bracket in the first regex, but you can save one byte by using ` |@` for the last one

Comment: @Leo Ooh, `|`, how very appropriate for this challenge!

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 31 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
₁F„@ Ω}JÐ₅ÝΩ©è„@ Â‡®ǝ‚16δôø'|ý»
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UVOj26OGeQ4K51bWeh2e8Kip9fDccysPrTy8Aix6uOlRw8JD647PfdQwy9Ds3JbDWw7vUK85vPfQ7v//AQ)

Replaced the incorrect `„@ ₁×.r₁£` with `₁F„@ ΩJ}` (also -1 byte) to fix the issue mentioned by *@Neil*: *"Strictly speaking, step 1 doesn't generate 256 independent characters; the chances for all `@`s is \$(256!)^2\$ in \$512!\$ instead of \$1\$ in \$2^{256}\$."*

**Explanation:**

Step 1: Generate a random string of 256 `"@"` and `" "`, with a 50% chance each:

```python
₁F           # Loop 256 times:
  „@         #  Push string "@ "
     Ω       #  Pop and push a random character from it
      }J     # After the loop: Join all characters on the stack together
```

[Try just step 1 online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UVOj26OGeQ4K51bWev3/DwA)

Step 2: Create a copy, and flip the character at a single random position:

```python
Ð             # Triplicate the string
 ₅Ý           # Push a list in the range [0,255]
   Ω          # Pop and push a random integer from it
    ©         # Store this random index-integer in variable `®` (without popping)
     è        # Pop one of the strings, and get the character at this index
      „@      # Push string "@ " again
        Â     # Bifurcate it; short for Duplicate & Reverse copy
         ‡    # Transliterate "@" to " " and vice-versa
          ®ǝ  # Pop another string, and insert this flipped character at index `®`
            ‚ # Pair the two strings together
```

[Try just the first two steps online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UVOj26OGeQ4K51bWeh2e8Kip9fDccysPrTy8Aix6uOlRw8JD647PfdQw6/9/AA)

Step 3: Format it correctly and output the result:

```python
  δ           # Map over both strings in the pair:
16 ô          #  Split it into parts of size 16 each
    ø         # Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns
     '|ý     '# Join each inner pair together with "|"-delimiter
        »     # Join the list of strings together by newlines
              # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Comment: Strictly speaking step 1 doesn't generate 256 independent characters; the chances for all `@`s is 1 in `512!` instead of 1 in `2^256`.

Comment: @Neil Good point. Fixed, and actually golfed by 1 byte in the process.

Comment: Sorry, I miscalculated, the all `@`s is actually `(256!)^2` in `512!` but that's still not the same as 1 in `2^256`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), 369 Bytes

```
(define(f x)(if(empty? x)x(cons(take x 16)(f(drop x 16)))))(let*([s list->string][b build-list][m map][g((λ(x)(list(m(λ(x y)(xor x y))x(b 256((λ(y)(λ(x)(= y x)))(random 256))))x))(b 256(λ(x)(=(random 2)0))))][h(λ(x)(m(λ(x)(if x #\@#\ ))x))][i(list(m s(f(h(car g))))(m s(f(h(cadr g)))))])(display(string-join(m(λ(x y)(string-append x"|"y))(car i)(cadr i))"\n")))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU9LbsUgELvKKNkMlSK1lfp2/dyDsCCB5E1f@AiolEi9We/QK6WQoLZswB5jj4Mcbzrt7SLtDOEEqPREVuMEK0OaUBufttcMVhydjZjkTcMKDxeGE6rg/AnKwUWnO@QRFoqpe4kpkJ0FH2D4oEV1hRXcgJFe8Bnx@wtzRGHRHAA2hqsLUB45boDHp8shy/wpfoYtb5KTgrTKmSIowZmq6ir7nbP7Mhf8Wiem3pTrQdu/tT0c3wWnugnE3OuKowwwH6X@GFUpJhgqin6RG54lu3dH9l@LykrvtVWwNp9NbnR4EjuNiLGmt0022/cf)

This is my first post here so I'm hoping I'm following all the rules.  I'm also still learning Racket so I'm sure this isn't optimized and I'm excited to receive any tips, but I wanted to post as far as I've gotten.  Below is a rough description of what's going on.

```scheme
#lang racket
;splits a list of 256 into 16 lists of 16
(define(f x)(if(empty? x)x(cons(take x 16)(f(drop x 16)))))

(let*(
      ;shorten reused functions
      [s list->string]
      [b build-list]
      [m map]

      ;generate a pair of boolean lists of lists differing by 1 entry
      [g((λ(x)(list(m(λ(x y)(xor x y))x(b 256((λ(y)(λ(x)(= y x)))(random 256))))x))(b 256(λ(x)(=(random 2)0))))]

      ;convert #t and #f into #\@ and #\ 
      [h(λ(x)(m(λ(x)(if x #\@#\ ))x))]

      ;create list of strings from list of list of chars
      [i(list(m s(f(h(car g))))(m s(f(h(cadr g)))))])

  ;concat strings
  (display(string-join(m(λ(x y)(string-append x"|"y))(car i)(cadr i))"\n")))
```

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 2):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 30 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Assume Index Origin is 0 (`⎕IO←0`)

```
' @|'[i,2,~@(⊂?⍴i)⊣i←?16 16⍴2]
```

[Try it on aplgolf](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=e9Q31dP/UdsEAwA&c=U1dwqFGPztQx0qlz0HjU1WT/qHdLpuajrsWZj9om2BuaKRiaAUWMYgE&f=AwA&i=SwMA&r=tio&l=apl-dyalog&m=dfn&n=f#)

```
⍝ Rough explaination

' @|'[i,2,~@(⊂?⍴i)⊣i←?16 16⍴2]
                   i←?16 16⍴2  ⍝ 1. i is a random 16 by 16 bit matrix
          ~@(⊂?⍴i)⊣i           ⍝ 2. i with one random bit toggled
      i,2,~@(⊂?⍴i)⊣i           ⍝ 3. Matrix of i, 2, and the toggled i
' @|'[                       ] ⍝ 4. Indexing into string ' @|'

⍝ Breakdown of step 2

          ~@(⊂?⍴i)⊣i
               ⍴i              ⍝ 2-1. The shape of i
              ?⍴i              ⍝ 2-2. A random index into i
          ~@(⊂?⍴i)             ⍝ 2-3. A function that toggles at the index
          ~@(⊂?⍴i)⊣i           ⍝ 2-4. i with one random bit toggled
```

## [ngn/k](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 32 bytes

```
+" @|".[i;2?#i;~:],2,i:16?+!16#2
```

[Try it online](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJzTVlJwqFHSi860NrJXzrSus4rVMdLJtDI0s9dWNDRTNgIAgn0HoQ==)

Comment: Nice. Could you add a [Try It online!](https://tio.run/#apl-dyalog) so we can see the output? Thanks.

Comment: @vengy I've added links to my answers.

Comment: Looks good! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## Swift, <s>179</s> <s>176</s> 169 bytes

```swift
var r=0..<16,a=r.map{_ in r.map{_ in !(.random())}},s={""+($0+[]).map{$0 ?"@":" "}}
zip(a,(a[.random(in:r)][.random(in:r)].toggle(),a).1).map{print(s($0.0)+"|"+s($0.1))}
```

Comment: @vengy Thanks for the catch! Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 30 bytes

```
↶≔¹⁶θＥθ⭆θ‽ @Ｃ⊕θ⁰θＪ‽θ±‽θ§ @⁼ ＫＫ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3BDoIwEETvfEXDaZvURC9euEiMB4waov5AAysSoKXtQvTrayEE9zRvd3ameEtbaNl6n9ejpgu@CHgSpc7VlYLdXjATMLe1IrjKHoxgDwpULXCXqtQdxOwQ8zBJdNT9FzJVWOxQEZZguGDbNWNKOw9d/9SwvE73G1aS8L/hqz@lTJX4mQsEO5lBti5A0DliA3On934ztj8) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
↶
```

Change the default drawing direction to upwards.

```
≔¹⁶θ
```

Save the value `16` in a variable because it gets used to much.

```
Ｅθ⭆θ‽ @
```

Output a random `16×16` grid of spaces and `@`s.

```
Ｃ⊕θ⁰
```

Copy it `17` characters to the right.

```
θ
```

Draw a line of length `16` in the default drawing direction.

```
Ｊ‽θ±‽θ
```

Jump to a random position.

```
§ @⁼ ＫＫ
```

Toggle the character at that position.

Answer (score 1):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 34 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Requires Index Origin 0 (`⎕IO←0`)

```
' @|'[A,2,A≠(⍴A←?16 16⍴2)⍴1=?⍨256]
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=e9Q31dP/UdsEAwA&c=U1dwqFGPdtQx0nF81LlA41HvFsdHbRPsDc0UDM2AHCNNIGFoa/@od4WRqVksAA&f=AwA&i=SwMA&r=tio&l=apl-dyalog&m=dfn&n=f)

```
' @|'[A,2,A≠(⍴A←?16 16⍴2)⍴1=?⍨256]­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‏​⁢⁠⁢‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁣​‎⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
                 16 16⍴2            # ‎⁡generate 16, 16 matrix of 2s
                ?                   # ‎⁢replace each with random number less than current value
              A←                    # ‎⁣assign to A
‎⁤
                            ?⍨256   # ‎⁢⁡random permutation of [0, 1, ..., 255]
                          1=        # ‎⁢⁢equals 1 (vectorized)
                         ⍴          # ‎⁢⁣reshape to
             ⍴A                     # ‎⁢⁤shape of A (16, 16)
          A≠                        # ‎⁣⁡not equal/xor against A (vectorized)
        2,                          # ‎⁣⁢concatenate column of 2 to start
      A,                            # ‎⁣⁣concatenate A to start
' @|'[                           ]  # ‎⁣⁤translate to required characters
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Answer (score 1):

## [Windows Batch Scripting](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting), <del>469</del> <del>262</del> 259 bytes

*Thanks to Neil's tips.*

```
@echo off&setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion&set/av=%random%%%256
for /L %%i in (0,1,255)do (set/ar=!random!%%2&set c= &if !r!==0 set c=@
set a=!a!!c!&if %%i==%v% if !c!==@ (set c= )else set c=@
set b=!b!!c!&set/ae=%%i%%16&if !e!==15 echo !a!^|!b!&set a=&set b=)
```

**Notes**

`EnableDelayedExpansion` Delayed Expansion will cause variables within a batch file to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time.

`%random%%%256` generates a random number in the range \$[0,255]\$.

**Output**

[image: out]

Comment: You can use `%%i` instead of `!n!`, and the last line can be `for /L %%i in (0,16,255)do echo !b:~%%i,16!^|!m:~%%i,16!`, and now `a` is also no longer necessary, and in the first loop you can also inline `c`. The `"`s are also mostly unnecessary, the exception being `if "!c!"=="@"`.

Comment: You don't actually need `c` in the first loop, you can just update `b` directly; this also allows you to remove the `()`s around the entire `do` block. You can also remove the `()`s from the command after the `else`s; they're only required before the `else`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Assembly (nasm, x64, Linux)](http://www.nasm.us/), 343 bytes

```
mov byte[l+16],'|' 
mov byte[l+33],10 
rdrand ax
movzx r12,al
mov bl,0
mov r14,16
p:mov rcx,16
mov r9,l
r:rdrand r8
and r8,1
mov al,[c+r8]
mov[r9],al
cmp r12,rbx
jne o
cmp al,64
je s
add al,32
jmp o
s:sub al,32
o:mov[r9+17],al
inc r9
inc bl
loop r
mov rax,1
mov rdi,1
mov rsi,l
mov rdx,34
syscall
dec r14
jnz p
c db "@ "
section .bss
l resb 34
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU@7boQwEOz3K1bXXIET4QORO9KkyVcgCr8KTgYjL4nMKf9ObMNFKazdmVnNjAWRGaVdXyZB47aN7hvlupjOFrzp2fnnjPCPq6qe8RLBay8mjSIk8RHQ8wsTdr@0rMyL5zXjDcxtBiokkNcbs@Dbw8JfYR@MZ1VY1qnCX/uEOn/rk68a5xzhZYD7ZNBlJp42NdwNEgitE6wucI@CA2rpSx6Ma3engr9ls2FSsUMe0oJ1LnrvxUQ4Sng9PDcamD24wKoaaCUlrAVtVPphrPPAGRRqiacPPAEZtQxuwldJBBa9IYlVvb1/hmH5S2lKCM7nmPientsv)

**Notes**

[rdrand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDRAND) is an instruction for returning random numbers from an Intel on-chip hardware random number generator.

Set `r12` to a random number \$[0,255]\$

```
rdrand ax
movzx r12,al
```

Set `r8` to a random number \$[0,1]\$

```
rdrand r8
and r8,1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-2) `j`, 169 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 21.125 bytes

```
₈ÞB:₈ṁ⁽¬V"ƛ‛ @i;ṅ²÷Zƛ\|j
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyI9aiIsIiIsIuKCiMOeQjrigojhuYHigb3CrFZcIsab4oCbIEBpO+G5hcKyw7daxptcXHxqIiwiIiwiIl0=)

Bitstring:

```
1010111011001011000000101101001010011100010010011000001111001011010101011001000001000110000001100000001001100110111011001000100101001001111010100000110110101011110100100
```

```
₈ÞB:₈ṁ⁽¬V"ƛ‛ @i;ṅ²÷Zƛ\|j­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
₈ÞB                       # ‎⁡256 random bits
   :₈ṁ⁽¬V                 # ‎⁢copy and flip a bit at a random index
         "                # ‎⁣pair them into a list
          ƛ    ;          # ‎⁤map over each
           ‛ @i           # ‎⁢⁡the corresponding index of the string " @" 
                ṅ²        # ‎⁢⁢concatenate, turn each string into a square
                  ÷Z      # ‎⁢⁣push each square and zip the two
                    ƛ\|j  # ‎⁢⁤join by |
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

[decoder (not at all golfed)](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#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)

Answer (score 1):

## [YASEPL](https://github.com/madeforlosers/YASEPL-esolang), 151 bytes

```
=v=a$64»=i£1=r¢0,255`1!s[3#pipe`3=j`2!s[7!o¥j,1!)o!g$16*i+j}7,r,9!)a!o}7,a,9!)" "`9!~|8`7!b)a!m¢0,1@6!b)" "`6!b~!1©b`8!j+}2,17,2!s@4$|`4=s£1>""!i+}2,17
```